# Monitor will not be detected, stuck at 640x480

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, resolution, monitor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting screen resolution correct with nvidia drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4253/getting-screen-resolution-correct-with-nvidia-drivers)

I'm completely new to Linux but know the basics of command entry. Here's what I've tried:
First off, I installed my restricted driver for my GeForce 8600 GT. That was the easy part but I got stuck at 1024x768. I looked at my `Xorg.0.log` and saw that I was using the vesa driver instead of the nv driver.

I tried running `sudo nvidia-xconfig` which made an xorg.conf file, but when I restarted was cut down to 640x480. In my `Xorg.0.log` I noticed in there that the EDID for my monitor was failing. Weird.

Output of `X.org.0.log`:

```
[    12.412] 
X.Org X Server 1.10.4
Release Date: 2011-08-19
[    12.412] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    12.412] Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.24-29-server x86_64 Ubuntu
[    12.412] Current Operating System: Linux Rserver 3.0.0-12-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 7 14:56:25 UTC 2011 x86_64
[    12.412] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-12-generic root=UUID=6fa39bcf-0be1-45e7-b163-80f5c4d8417e ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[    12.412] Build Date: 19 October 2011  05:21:26AM
[    12.412] xorg-server 2:1.10.4-1ubuntu4.2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[    12.412] Current version of pixman: 0.22.2
[    12.412]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    12.412] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    12.412] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Tue Nov  1 17:10:16 2011
[    12.412] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[    12.412] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    12.412] (==) ServerLayout "Layout0"
[    12.412] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
[    12.412] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
[    12.413] (**) |   |-->Device "Device0"
[    12.413] (**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
[    12.413] (**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
[    12.413] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    12.413] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    12.413] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    12.413]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    12.413] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    12.413]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    12.413] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    12.413]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    12.413] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    12.413]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    12.413] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    12.413]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    12.413] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType,
    built-ins
[    12.413] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    12.413] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[    12.413] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
[    12.413] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
[    12.413] (II) Loader magic: 0x7e0220
[    12.413] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    12.413]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    12.413]    X.Org Video Driver: 10.0
[    12.413]    X.Org XInput driver : 12.3
[    12.413]    X.Org Server Extension : 5.0
[    12.414] (--) PCI:*(0:5:0:0) 10de:0421:1458:344c rev 161, Mem @ 0xfd000000/16777216, 0xc0000000/536870912, 0xfa000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000dc00/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[    12.414] (II) Open ACPI successful (/var/run/acpid.socket)
[    12.414] (II) LoadModule: "extmod"
[    12.415] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libextmod.so
[    12.415] (II) Module extmod: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    12.415]    compiled for 1.10.4, module version = 1.0.0
[    12.415]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    12.415]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 5.0
[    12.415] (II) Loading extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[    12.415] (II) Loading extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[    12.415] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DGA
[    12.415] (II) Loading extension DPMS
[    12.415] (II) Loading extension XVideo
[    12.415] (II) Loading extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[    12.415] (II) Loading extension X-Resource
[    12.415] (II) LoadModule: "dbe"
[    12.415] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdbe.so
[    12.415] (II) Module dbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    12.415]    compiled for 1.10.4, module version = 1.0.0
[    12.415]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    12.415]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 5.0
[    12.415] (II) Loading extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[    12.415] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    12.415] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/libglx.so
[    12.872] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    12.872]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    12.872]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    12.872] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  280.13  Wed Jul 27 17:12:07 PDT 2011
[    12.872] (II) Loading extension GLX
[    12.872] (II) LoadModule: "record"
[    12.872] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/librecord.so
[    12.872] (II) Module record: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    12.872]    compiled for 1.10.4, module version = 1.13.0
[    12.872]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    12.872]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 5.0
[    12.872] (II) Loading extension RECORD
[    12.872] (II) LoadModule: "dri"
[    12.873] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri.so
[    12.873] (II) Module dri: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    12.873]    compiled for 1.10.4, module version = 1.0.0
[    12.873]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 5.0
[    12.873] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DRI
[    12.873] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[    12.873] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri2.so
[    12.873] (II) Module dri2: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    12.873]    compiled for 1.10.4, module version = 1.2.0
[    12.873]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 5.0
[    12.873] (II) Loading extension DRI2
[    12.873] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    12.873] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
[    12.874] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    12.874]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    12.874]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    12.874] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  280.13  Wed Jul 27 16:55:26 PDT 2011
[    12.874] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[    12.874] (++) using VT number 7

[    12.874] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[    12.874] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    12.891] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    12.891] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    12.891]    compiled for 1.10.4, module version = 1.0.0
[    12.891]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    12.891] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
[    12.891] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
[    12.892] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[    12.892] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    12.892]    compiled for 1.10.4, module version = 1.0.0
[    12.892]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    12.892] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[    12.892] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[    12.892] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[    12.892] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
[    12.892] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[    12.892] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    12.892] (**) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[    12.892] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[    12.892] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    12.892] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    12.892] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "NoLogo" "True"
[    12.892] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "AddARGBGLXVisuals" "True"
[    13.629] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Unable to read EDID for display device CRT-1
[    13.632] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU GeForce 8500 GT (G86) at PCI:5:0:0 (GPU-0)
[    13.632] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 524288 kBytes
[    13.632] (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 60.86.34.00.13
[    13.632] (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
[    13.632] (--) NVIDIA(0): Interlaced video modes are supported on this GPU
[    13.632] (--) NVIDIA(0): Connected display device(s) on GeForce 8500 GT at PCI:5:0:0
[    13.632] (--) NVIDIA(0):     CRT-1
[    13.632] (--) NVIDIA(0): CRT-1: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    13.661] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID has been
[    13.661] (**) NVIDIA(0):     enabled on all display devices.
[    13.662] (II) NVIDIA(0): Assigned Display Device: CRT-1
[    13.662] (WW) NVIDIA(0): No valid modes for "1360x768"; removing.
[    13.662] (WW) NVIDIA(0): 
[    13.662] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Unable to validate any modes; falling back to the default mode
[    13.662] (WW) NVIDIA(0):     "nvidia-auto-select".
[    13.662] (WW) NVIDIA(0): 
[    13.662] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated modes:
[    13.662] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "nvidia-auto-select"
[    13.662] (**) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size configured to be 1360 x 768
[    13.696] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Unable to get display device CRT-1's EDID; cannot compute DPI
[    13.697] (WW) NVIDIA(0):     from CRT-1's EDID.
[    13.697] (==) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (75, 75); computed from built-in default
[    13.697] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 32-bit ARGB GLX visuals.
[    13.697] (--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[    13.697] (II) NVIDIA: Using 768.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory access.
[    13.703] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "nvidia-auto-select"
[    13.727] (II) Loading extension NV-GLX
[    13.752] (==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
[    13.752] (==) NVIDIA(0): Backing store disabled
[    13.752] (==) NVIDIA(0): Silken mouse enabled
[    13.753] (**) NVIDIA(0): DPMS enabled
[    13.753] (II) Loading extension NV-CONTROL
[    13.753] (II) Loading extension XINERAMA
[    13.753] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[    13.753] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[    13.753] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri2.so
[    13.753] (II) Module dri2: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    13.753]    compiled for 1.10.4, module version = 1.2.0
[    13.753]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 5.0
[    13.753] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[    13.753] (==) RandR enabled
[    13.753] (II) Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[    13.753] (II) Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[    13.753] (II) Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[    13.753] (II) Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[    13.753] (II) Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[    13.753] (II) Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[    13.753] (II) Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[    13.753] (II) Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[    13.753] (II) Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[    13.753] (II) Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
[    13.753] (II) Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[    13.753] (II) Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[    13.753] (II) Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[    13.754] (II) Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[    13.754] (II) Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[    13.754] (II) Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[    13.754] (II) Initializing built-in extension GESTURE
[    13.755] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[    13.846] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[    13.854] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event1)
[    13.854] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    13.855] (II) LoadModule: "evdev"
[    13.855] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    13.855] (II) Module evdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    13.856]    compiled for 1.10.2, module version = 2.6.0
[    13.856]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[    13.856]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 12.3
[    13.856] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[    13.856] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    13.856] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    13.856] (**) Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event1"
[    13.856] (--) Power Button: Found keys
[    13.856] (II) Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[    13.856] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input1/event1"
[    13.856] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD)
[    13.856] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    13.856] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    13.856] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    13.858] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event0)
[    13.858] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    13.858] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[    13.858] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    13.858] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    13.858] (**) Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event0"
[    13.858] (--) Power Button: Found keys
[    13.858] (II) Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[    13.858] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0/event0"
[    13.858] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD)
[    13.858] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    13.858] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    13.858] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    13.860] (II) config/udev: Adding input device USB Optical Mouse (/dev/input/event3)
[    13.860] (**) USB Optical Mouse: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[    13.860] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'USB Optical Mouse'
[    13.860] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    13.860] (**) USB Optical Mouse: always reports core events
[    13.860] (**) USB Optical Mouse: Device: "/dev/input/event3"
[    13.860] (--) USB Optical Mouse: Found 3 mouse buttons
[    13.860] (--) USB Optical Mouse: Found scroll wheel(s)
[    13.860] (--) USB Optical Mouse: Found relative axes
[    13.860] (--) USB Optical Mouse: Found x and y relative axes
[    13.860] (II) USB Optical Mouse: Configuring as mouse
[    13.860] (II) USB Optical Mouse: Adding scrollwheel support
[    13.860] (**) USB Optical Mouse: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[    13.860] (**) USB Optical Mouse: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[    13.860] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/input/input3/event3"
[    13.860] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "USB Optical Mouse" (type: MOUSE)
[    13.860] (II) USB Optical Mouse: initialized for relative axes.
[    13.860] (**) USB Optical Mouse: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[    13.860] (**) USB Optical Mouse: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[    13.860] (**) USB Optical Mouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    13.860] (**) USB Optical Mouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    13.861] (II) config/udev: Adding input device USB Optical Mouse (/dev/input/mouse0)
[    13.861] (II) No input driver/identifier specified (ignoring)
[    13.862] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel Headphone (/dev/input/event4)
[    13.862] (II) No input driver/identifier specified (ignoring)
[    13.869] (II) config/udev: Adding input device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard (/dev/input/event2)
[    13.869] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    13.869] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
[    13.869] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    13.869] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: always reports core events
[    13.869] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Device: "/dev/input/event2"
[    13.869] (--) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Found keys
[    13.869] (II) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Configuring as keyboard
[    13.869] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input2/event2"
[    13.869] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD)
[    13.869] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    13.869] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    13.869] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    17.242] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-A77BBE312A49C9FE89948D38B2A8CB84C3CBB410.xkm
```

***My `xorg.conf`***

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 280.13  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-03.nvidia.com)  Wed Jul 27 17:15:58 PDT 2011


Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "AddARGBGLXVisuals" "True"
    Option         "NoLogo" "True"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

And if I try using `xrandr` in the customary fashion (just to get back to 1024x768), I get:

```
    xrandr --output default --mode "1024x768_60.00"
    xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
    xrandr: screen cannot be larger than 640x480 (desired size 1024x768)
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at this question - [Getting screen resolution correct with nvidia drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4253/getting-screen-resolution-correct-with-nvidia-drivers)? Does it prove helpful to you?