# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Screen resolution - Second screen giving a lower resolution

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, display-resolution

I am using NVIDIA GeForce GT710 graphics card. I tried every driver by nvidia. nvidia-396, nvidia-390, nvidia-390. All gave the issue of reduced resolution in the second screen connected via HDMI-0. Whenever I try generating xorg.conf file using nvidia-settings, I get a blank second screen.

```
$ uname -r
4.4.0-131-generic
```

Tried [Getting screen resolution correct with nvidia drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4253/getting-screen-resolution-correct-with-nvidia-drivers?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), but generating an xorg.conf file results in the second screen getting blank.

The second screen can support 1920x1080_60. Tried adding using xrandr, newmode and addmode steps. It doesn't help either.

Please help.

Regards,
Ramkumar.